# ESLint: how to automatically --fix export/import to be always multiline?

Tags: javascript, formatting, eslint

I use ESLint with prettier (running eslint with `--fix` formats the code according to ESLint rules).

I want to have have exports always multiline. I have tried every combination I can think of, but the result doesn't add up.

Related ESLint rule: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/object-curly-newline

What I want is this:

Before formatting:

```
export { a, b, c, d }
```

After formatting:

```
export {
  a,
  b,
  c,
  d
}
```

If it's a single export, either would be fine:

```
export { a }
// Or
export {
  a
}
```

Is it possible to have `--fix` do this? The closest I can get is:

```
export {
  a, b, c, d
}
```